# Find if a ViewController is already on the stack of views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to check if my view has already been added to the view, so that the user cannot repeatedly add the new UIViewController onto the view.

```
    if (!self.fmovc)
    {
        self.fmovc = [[FMOVC alloc] initWithNibName: @"FMOVC" bundle:nil];
    }

    BOOL viewAlreadyDisplayed = NO;
    for (UIView * b in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([b isKindOfClass:[FMOVC class]])
        {
            viewAlreadyDisplayed = YES;
        }
    }

    if (!viewAlreadyDisplayed)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:self.fmovc.view];
    }
```

This is not working because it never triggers

```
viewAlreadyDisplayed = YES;
```

What is the correct way to go about finding if your view is already being displayed?

Thanks,
-Code

Comment: Following your code you want to add viewController inside view? This does not have logic to me? You want to check if some viewController is already pushed/presented or if some view is already subviewed?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but the reason your code is not working is because you are doing "([b isKindOfClass:[FMOVC class]])", FMOVC is a viewcontroller and b is a UIView. I did not test it out, but you can try "b==self.fmovc.view" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding just removeItFromSuperView...It may solve your prob

```
    [self.fmovc.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.fmovc.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the UIView member variable say thatView;

if(!thatView) {
thatView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:thatView];
}

Once you release the superview, release thatView & make thatView to nil.

OR

always check & remove thatView if present from superview before allocating thatView.

Hope this Helps !!!